# how can I make the click event correspond to the selected?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have created a class named "check".The class should turn the selected box 
   to 
   yellow.my issue is that if I do  the click, all the iterated boxes would turn 
   to yellow, not 
   only the selected one .

```
<template>
  <div>
  <!--iterated object-->
    <div class="main" v-for="rr,index in object">
      <p class="paragraph">{{rr.genre}}</p>
      <!-- check box iterated with the object-->
      <div :class="{'checkBox':true, check:checked}" @click="work(index)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      data() {
         return {
            object:[],
            checked:false
         }
      , mounted() {
         axios.get("/maria")
         .then(response => this.object = response.data);
        },
        methods: {
              work(index) {
              this.checked=!this.checked
            }
        }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some relation between `checked` and the clicked row. For example let `checked` be equal to the index or even better the `id` of the last clicked item like so:

```
    methods: {
        work(index) {
          this.checked = index
        }
    }
```

And modify the condition for applying the class:

```
<div :class="{'checkBox':true, check: checked == index}" @click="work(index)"></div>
```

Comment: I was just thinking the same but couldn't figure it out. thanks for the help ^^